# Did Kichikuou Rance really save Alicesoft from bankrupcy?

Tags: sengoku-rance

No doubt *Kichikuou Rance* is a timeless classic and arguably the best in the *Rance* series (maybe just not as well known to the western audience as Sengoku Rance). I just wonder whether it's true that Alicesoft was on the verge of bankruptcy at that time, so they threw every remaining idea into *Kichikuou Rance*, whose sales revived the company.

I remember reading that on some Wiki but I can't seem to find it now, at least not via Google. I just found some forum posts on the topic.

Is there any source (e.g. interview with Alicesoft people) that explains the matter?

Comment: I expect you heard this on the [Alicesoft wiki](http://alicesoft.wikia.com/wiki/Kichikuou_Rance).  That link in particular claims that Alicesoft did intentionally try to incorporate everything they could think of about the franchise into the game "just in case" they went bankrupt.  Though I don't see any evidence supporting that claim.